# Handle keyboard in C++ in cross-platform way

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, cross-platform

I have created an application in C++ using Qt. I want that if the user clicked on the button named `btnA` ,then the program should emulate it as if <kbd>A</kbd> is pressed.

I searched on google and came up to a platform dependent solution. I want it to be cross platform .Is there any API ? I would prefer cross-platform(or linux) solution.

Edit:-

here is my code and its not wrking :-

```
#include "calculator.h"
#include "ui_calculator.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>

Calculator::Calculator(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Calculator),
    DisplayString("")
{
     ui->setupUi(this);
     setFixedSize(this->size());

    //Connected all buttons to one slot 
     connect(ui->Button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button3,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button4,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button5,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button6,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button7,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button8,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button9,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->Button0,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));

     connect(ui->ButtonAddition,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->ButtonMinus,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->ButtonModulas,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->ButtonDivide,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
     connect(ui->ButtonMultiplication,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(CalButtonPressed()));
}

Calculator::~Calculator()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Calculator::CalButtonPressed()
{
    QPushButton *senderbtn = static_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    QString string = senderbtn->text();

    char ch = string.at(0).toLatin1();
// for testing I have taken only one button
    QKeyEvent * event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress,Qt::Key_A,Qt::NoModifier,nullptr);
    QApplication::postEvent(ui->Input,event);


}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <cstring>
#include "calculator.h"

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    QApplication *app= new QApplication(argc,argv);
    app->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Icon.png"));


    Calculator *cal = new Calculator(nullptr);
    cal->show();

    return  app->exec();

}
```

It should display 'a' in `QLineEdit` widget named `Input`

Comment: Your code is incomplete - you've forgotten to include the contents of `"calculator.h"` and `"ui_calculator.h"`.  You can also make it more minimal - it only needs a single button, not fifteen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `QKeyEvent` for this as shown below.

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A, Qt::NoModifier, 0);
```

The above syntax creates a `QKeyEvent` of type `KeyPress`, with the key pressed as <kbd>A</kbd> and tells that there was no modifier pressed in the process.

Once that is created, you can add it to the eventQueue using `postEvent`.

```
QApplication::postEvent(this, event);
```

Qt Documentations that you can go through for better understanding of what you are going to use :

- [QApplication::postEvent(..)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent)
- [QKeyEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#QKeyEvent)

I have used the above in case of a cross-platform solution for Windows and Mac. Hopefully, It would work just fine for linux as well.

---

**Update :**

Since you want to update the line edit with the text, you need to do the following :

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A, Qt::NoModifier, QKeySequence(Qt::Key_A).toString());
// This is because QLineEdit does not deduce the text from the event type, but instead just adds the text it receives.
```

This will surely update the `QLineEdit` with the character 'A' when the `button A` is pressed. Obviously after you call `postEvent` with the new `event` that is created above.

Comment: Thank, Can you tell me that how can I use it with `shift+ =` so that I can print '+' and other special symbols ?

Comment: In the documentation that I have posted above, have a look at the [Key enum list](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum). Look for options like `Key_Equal` or `Key_Plus`.

Additionally, when you want to consider the shift modifier as well, then change the param of the `QKeyEvent` from `Qt::NoModifier` to `Qt::ShiftModifier`.

Comment: The documentation is extremely rich, you will find whatever you need :)

Comment: Pls see my edited question . due to some rezone sits not working pls tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: Where is your edited question ? Add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the error you get.

Comment: I am not getting no error .its just not showing result